# make an image from arrays python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I have 1d numpy arrays x, y, z where z is considered the value of some quantity at (x,y).
The position arrays (x,y) are not uniformly sampled.

Can I easily construct and plot an image z(x,y) in python?

Comment: interpolate: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html

Comment: Maybe you want a library like matplotlib or pyqtgraph